# Intellij Idea built jar not containing /src directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, filepath

I have built my jar file with Intellij IDEA.
Somewhere in my code I have this static dynamic filepath for my fxml files:

```
private static URL fxmlResourcePath2 =
        new URL("file://" + System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + File.separator
                + "src"
                + File.separator
                + "dev"
                + File.separator
                + "folling"
                + File.separator
                + "resources"
                + File.separator
                + "fxml"
                + File.separator
        )
```

note I've also tried many other versions, such as

```
    private static URL fxmlResourcePath =
        new URL("file://" + new File(
                "src${File.separator}"+
                "dev${File.separator}" +
                "folling${File.separator}" +
                "resources${File.separator}" +
                "fxml${File.separator}").absolutePath + File.separator
        )
```

Now this works perfectly fine with
[my current project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D66fM.png)
Though as soon as I build the jar, the `/src` directory disappears, as visible after a quick `jar tf thejarofsubject.jar > output.txt` 
where a quick search for "src" yields nothing. Unpacking the jar reveals it immediately begins with the `/dev` directory. I can't just remove the "src" from my dynamic path as it will otherwise not run in my IDE, but I also can't just keep it as it'll not work outside of the IDE in that case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use the resource root type which will be copied to classpath and load resources from classpath instead.

Comment: While that didn't clear why it didn't work, changing it to load by resource did fix it, thank you very much!